# Create an Array with the numbers of post of an other array :

Tags: python

So here is my problem :

```
toto = [1,4,5,2,4,7]
```

this array as 6 posts

So i would like to obtain an array with 6 posts going 0 to 5 (result here) from the toto array

```
print(result)
..[0,1,2,3,4,5]
```

Something more elegant than :

```
result = []
i = 0
for t in toto :
    result.push(i)
    i = i +1
```

Comment: Please take a minute to read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and consider edit your question to be a bit more clear. Your question should include an attempt to solve the problem, beware that StackOverflow isn't a coding service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `range` between `0` and the length of `toto`:

```
result = list(range(0, len(toto)))
```